# Is there a name for a 3D snow globe?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I tried to do my best to describe this

[image: image of a winter landscape in a snow globe]

I wanted to buy one. And when I tried to explain to the man what I wanted I looked like an idiot moving my hands back and forth to show him how it works. A 3D globe can confuse people, undoubtedly.

How would we most clearly refer to it? Is there any single word describing it?

Comment: It's a snow globe.  You can buy it with the 3D money in your 3D wallet.  That's just what my 3D brain thinks.

Comment: I've never seen a snow globe that was *not* 3D.

Comment: _globe_ : ["something spherical"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/globe) ; _sphere:_ [" a three-dimensional shape"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sphere).

Comment: Are you sure it's 3D? I keep trying to pick up the 3D snow globe in the question but i can't get my hand past this invisible force shield. Maybe I'm just hitting the 4th wall.

Comment: i told you it's gonna be better for everybody if the man goes on explaining it with his HANDS

Comment: @margana careful, you're going to get this question moved to mathematics. = )

Comment: I think the single word to describe it, at least when it's about to fall, is "Rosebud".

Comment: @Margana, so you'd go with Rosebud? "What would you like sir?" "Hey, I don't know how to explain that but I would like a rosebud toy" and again without a HAND

Comment: I'm afraid the salesman would give you smth inappropriate

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want a word to show that the globe itself is 3D, or that the little models inside it are 3D?

Comment: i've been googling for the name for hours but did't find anything, i want a single word, i just want to know how we would most clearly name that in a store without having to hand-explain everything, 3d snow globe is very confusing, i want to find a single word

Comment: @Sydney maybe on to something but i don't think a single word is the way to solve this. Steve, is this an example what your trying to avoid: http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://shop.grandcanyonlodges.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/4/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/c/gc_snowglobe_65447-lsg_001_copy.jpg&imgrefurl=https://shop.grandcanyonlodges.com/shop/souvenirs/grand-canyon-double-view-snowglobe.html&h=1977&w=2617&tbnid=wiw5J0Y1bcPR_M:&docid=T8VxatEvbZiDGM&hl=en-US&ei=7c3XVarBIoHp-AHprLiYBw&tbm=isch&client=ms-android-att-us&ved=0CFwQMyguMC5qFQoTCOrr2M_Cu8cCFYE0PgodaRYOcw

Comment: @CandiedOrange yes. i don't want that

Comment: Steve, the standard term for the object shown in the photo attached to your question is "snow globe"—that's what the vast majority of people in the United States (at least) would call it if asked without any prompting about 3D or whatever. Thanks for being a good sport about the teasing that your question seems to have elicited from several jocular site users.

Comment: Re "Rosebud": [about 2:20 onwards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-r0b_XeRkG4). One of those moments.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue you've run into is that when you say "3D snow globe" the 3D is seen as modifying the whole of the snow globe and not the scene within the snow globe.

Rather than using some single word to solve this problem I recommend using a more exact explanation:

> I would like to buy a snow globe that contains a 3D scene inside.  Not just a picture.

That should help you avoid globes like this:

[image: 3D Snow globe with a 2D picture of Grand Canyon National Park inside]

I do appreciate you being a good sport while we have fun with our confusion.

Comment: I have seen maybe two such fake "snow globes" (containing pictures) in my 66 years of existence.  I suppose at one time there was an economic reason for making them, but any more injection molding (or 3D printing, for "one-off" units) is so economical that there's no point in making them.

Comment: @HotLicks I can only assume you don't spend much time in tourist traps.

Comment: Not if I can avoid it.

Comment: @HotLicks: ooh, that's a positive "anymore," right? That expression always confuses me temporarily.

Comment: @sumelic -- "Any more", in the above context, means "in modern times", or "now, vs several (dozen) years ago".

Comment: "Snow globe" is enough.  Not only because the kind the OP wants is so much more common than the other kind, but because the store has all its stock out on the shelves.  Once Steve has been led to the shelf with the snow globes, he can just pick out the one he wants to buy, or else leave disappointed because none of them were suitable.

Comment: @aparente001 I can only assume you don't spend much time in tourist traps either.  Yes, in some contexts snowglobes containing pictures are rare.  But say he owns a shop and wants to make clear to his supplier that his customers don't want cheap picture filled snow globes.  I can't blame him for wanting to learn how to make himself understood.  In fact, I admire it.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - "I wanted to buy one."  I figure, the shop either has one or it doesn't....

Comment: @aparente001 yes, but maybe he'd rather not be dragged through the store on a wild goose chance simply because he was misunderstood.

Comment: Speaking from a (North) European perspective, I can say that my experience is the exact opposite of Hot Licks’ and aparente001’s: the ‘2D’ versions are **much** more common (and cheap) than the ‘3D’ versions around these parts.